# monitor system users on raspberry pi with akka actors

Tags: scala, raspberry-pi, akka, actor

I've a raspberry pi on my network with an LED strip attached to it.
My purpose is to create a jar file that will sit on the pi, monitor system events such as logins and load average, and drive the LED based on the those inputs.

To continuosly monitor the logged in users, I am trying to use akka actors. Using the examples provided [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html), this is what I've gotten so far :

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin

import sys.process._

import akka.actor.{Actor, Props, ActorSystem}
import scala.concurrent.duration._


val who :String = "who".!!

class Blinker extends Actor {

  private def gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance
  private def led = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_08)

  def receive = {
    case x if who.contains("pi") => led.blink(250)
    case x if who.contains("moocow") => println("falalalala")
  }

  val blinker = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Blinker], this))

  val cancellable =  system.scheduler.schedule(
    0 milliseconds,
    50 milliseconds,
    blinker,
    who)
}
```

However, `system` is not recognised by my IDE (IntelliJ) and it says, `cannot resolve symbol`

I also have a main object like this:

```
object ledStrip  {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val blink = new Blinker
    // blink.receive

  }

}
```

In `main`, I'm not quite sure how to initialise the application.

Needless to say, this my first time writing a scala program
Help?

**Edit::**

Here is the updated program after incorporating what Michal has said

```
class Blinker extends Actor {

  val who: String = "who".!!

  private val gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance
  private val led = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_08)

  def receive = {
    case x if who.contains("pi") => led.blink(250)
    case x if who.contains("moocow") => println("falalalala")
  }

  val system = ActorSystem()


}



object ledStrip  extends  Blinker {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val blinker = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Blinker], this))
    import system.dispatcher

    val cancellable =
    system.scheduler.schedule(
      50 milliseconds,
      5000 milliseconds,
      blinker,
      who)

  }

}
```

This program compiles fine, but throws the following error upon execution:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   ledStrip.main(ledStrip.scala) Caused by:
>   akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance
>   of [ledStrip$] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use
>   one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the
>   documentation.    at
>   akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:194)   at
>   akka.actor.Actor.$init$(Actor.scala:472)  at
>   Blinker.(ledStrip.scala:15)     at
>   ledStrip$.(ledStrip.scala:34)   at
>   ledStrip$.(ledStrip.scala)    ... 1 more

**Edit 2**

Code that compiles and runs (behaviour is still not as desired)< `blink(1500)` is never executed when user: `pi` logs out from the shell>

```
object sysUser {
  val who: String = "who".!!
}

class Blinker extends Actor {

  private val gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance
  private val led = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_08)

  def receive = {
    case x if x.toString.contains("pi")  => led.blink(50)
    case x if x.toString.contains("moocow")  => println("falalalala")
    case _ => led.blink(1500)
  }
}

object ledStrip  {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem()

    val blinker = system.actorOf(Props[Blinker], "blinker")
    import system.dispatcher

    val cancellable =
      system.scheduler.schedule(
        50 milliseconds,
        5000 milliseconds,
        blinker,
        sysUser.who)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you haven't defined "system" anywhere. See this example for instance:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#here-is-another-example-that-you-can-edit-and-run-in-the-browser-

you'll find this line there:

```
 val system = ActorSystem("pingpong")
```

That's what creates the ActorSystem and defines the val called "system", which you then call methods on.

In the main, I don't think you want to create another instance with "new Blinker", just use:

```
system.actorOf(Props[Blinker], "blinker")
```

(which you are already doing and putting it into the "blinker" val)

Comment: Hi Michal. Thanks for your response. I've edited the original question, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is just a akka usage issue. I don't know why you do something seems strange, so I change them for `change1, change2, change3`, FYI.

```
class Blinker extends Actor {
  val who: String = "who".!!

  private val gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance
  private val led = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_08)

  def receive = {
    case x if who.contains("pi") => led.blink(250)
    case x if who.contains("moocow") => println("falalalala")
  }
}

object ledStrip { // change1
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem() // change2

    val blinker = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Blinker])) // change3
    import system.dispatcher

    val cancellable =
    system.scheduler.schedule(
      50 milliseconds,
      5000 milliseconds,
      blinker,
      who)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey lagom, thank you for your response. In your program, 'who' in the ledStrip Object "cannot be resolved"

Comment: I just copy from your code, your old code should also have this problem. Anyway, you can use `import scala.sys.process._ ` to fix this.

Comment: my first code draft didn't have the problem because object ledStrip was extended with 'Blinker'. that is where 'who' has been defined.

Comment: Oh, I missed it, it's a string, why do not move it to `object ledStrip`?

Comment: because I want to use it in `def receive` match cases

Comment: So why in `object ledStrip` you send `who` to the actor? You `def receive` did not use it. Your message received is `x`, but never used, you can send anything.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for bearing with me all along and helping me out, much appreciated. I should be able to make progress from here

Comment: Glad to help you.